# Как очистить QV/QHBoxLayout от всех элементов?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlayout

Изначально все элементы добавляются из БД пользователя через `for`. То есть не имеют переменных. 
При добавлении нового элемента нужно очистить старый список элементов, но мне это не удаётся сделать.

Пробовал так очищать `BoxLayout`, но получается какая то каша из новых и старых элементов:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.content = QFrame()

        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(64,74,85);
            ''')
        self.left_bar.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

        self.sidebar()

    def sidebar(self):
        # вместо списка из бд засунул сюда список чисел по которым будут создаваться кнопки
        # чтобы упростить код и не присваивать каждой итерации иконку из бд, имя кнопки и т.д.
        self.sidebarDataList = [1, 2, 3]
        for menuElement in self.sidebarDataList:
            item = QPushButton()
            item.setText(str(menuElement))

            self.vbox_1.addWidget(item)
        self.vbox_1.addStretch()

        self.plusMenuButton = QPushButton()
        self.plusMenuButton.setText("+")
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.plusMenuButton)
        self.plusMenuButton.clicked.connect(self.evt_plusItem)

    # Здесь нужно очистить список из кнопок в BoxLayout и сгенерировать по новой
    def evt_plusItem(self):
        self.sidebarDataList.append(4)
        countBoxMenu = self.vbox_1.count()
        for i in range(countBoxMenu):
            item = self.vbox_1.itemAt(i)
            self.vbox_1.removeItem(item)
        self.sidebar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Написал более полный код. Мне нужно чтобы когда кнопка в QVBoxLayout добавляется, этот QVBoxLayout обновлялся. То есть если кнопка не рисуется сразу, тогда все элементы нужно удалить и заново прорисовать с уже актуальным набором виджетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понимаю зачем вам нужно очистить старый список?

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        
# ???        self.content = QFrame()

        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(64,74,85);
            ''')
        self.left_bar.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter) # +
        self.hbox_1 = QHBoxLayout(self.right_bar)     # +
        self.hbox_1.addWidget(self.label)             # +

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

#        self.sidebar()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.count_item = 0
        self.sidebarDataList = [1, 2, 3]
        
        for item in self.sidebarDataList:
            self.sidebar(item)
        
        self.vbox_1.addStretch()

        self.plusMenuButton = QPushButton()
        self.plusMenuButton.setText("+")
        self.plusMenuButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: #B5FE83;')
        self.plusMenuButton.clicked.connect(self.evt_plusItem)        
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.plusMenuButton)        

    def sidebar(self, item):
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setText(f'Button {item}')
            
        button.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D98C00;')
        button.clicked.connect(
            lambda ch, btn=button: self.label.setText(f'Вы нажали кнопку: {btn.text()}'))
           
#        self.vbox_1.addWidget(button)    
        self.vbox_1.insertWidget(self.count_item, button) 
        self.count_item += 1        
    
    def evt_plusItem(self):
        self.sidebar(self.count_item+1)
        self.label.clear()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, это то что нужно!